# Prevent Windows 7 PC from sleeping while a download is in progress

Tags: windows-7, sleep, power

While I'm downloading a large file on Windows 7 using Google Chrome, my computer goes to sleep. I could obviously set the computer to not sleep at all (or change the interval before the computer sleeps).

What I want to know is: Is there a way to make Windows 7 not sleep as long as a download is in progress? (perhaps when any network activity is going on?). I've looked in the Advanced Power settings, and haven't seen any obvious setting.

Comment: Windows 7's presentation mode does the same. You can turn it on and off via the Mobility Center (Win+X). I Cannot post this as an answer cause the question is protected

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check this tool: [Insomnia](http://www.sevenforums.com/software/28125-msdn-blogger-releases-insomnia-keeping-windows-7-a.html) which prevent the computer from going into sleep mode while the program is open.

Comment: Insomnia is a very useful tool. Thanks for sharing it. Two small issues: As another answerer said, this feature should be wired into Chrome. (Not a solution, and thus not a useful answer, but true all the same.) Also, the Insomnia binary is not signed. I guess it costs too much to buy certificates just for software that you give away, but I wish we could have more rigorous use of security features like code signing..

Comment: Well the question was about preventing the computer from sleeping while a transfer is going on and while this program does this it seems a bit overkill as it doesn't care if an xfer is happening it just looks for any open program and keeps the machine awake.  

The program you want to check out is called coffee and it looks for transfers in progress and keeps everything runnning while they are: http://sourceforge.net/projects/coffee-sc/

Of course to be fair to karatchov, this program probably wasn't even born when he posted that comment but it is now :)

Answer (score 10):

It is the duty of the downloading program to reset the system idle timer by calling **[SetThreadExecutionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208%28VS.85%29.aspx)** with **ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED**.

Maybe you are lucky filing a bug/feature request at [google code](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list)

Answer (score 1):

[FlashGet](http://www.flashget.com/en/download.htm) has the option to put the PC in sleep mode after all downloads complete.

Comment: Thanks, John T. That's a good partial solution. I was hoping for a solution that would work if there were other kinds of network traffic going on, too (scp, ssh).

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to file a Chrome bug or send a feature request (although they probably won't listen to the latter). Chrome is still a relatively young browser, and I wouldn't expect Google to have though of minute details like this.

Otherwise, no, there is no global option to do this in Windows, and I doubt there is a utility to do what you want, although maybe something will pop up.

Answer (score 1):

" AMP WinOFF " is the best solution I've found
It can autoshutdown at certain conditions u specify e.g. CPU load, network activity ....etc

here it is :
http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Launchers-Shutdown-Tools/AMP-WinOFF.shtml

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox, you can install the **[No Sleep Download](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/no-sleep-download/)** extension. It prevents your computer from going to sleep while downloading files.

Also, [**Free Download Manager**](http://freedownloadmanager.org/download.htm), which integrates with Firefox, Opera, Chrome, IE, among other browsers, has a feature to prevent the computer from going into standby / sleep mode while it is downloading a file.

Comment: I know OP asked for solutions for Chrome. I am putting this solution for Firefox and other browsers as other similar and more general questions are being closed as a duplicate of this one.