# Is it possible to prevent the win7 sleep state while using spotify?

Tags: windows-7, audio, sleep

Does anyone know if there is a way to prevent windows 7 to go to sleep while using Spotify?

I have read the answers in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/18285/prevent-windows-7-pc-from-sleeping-while-a-download-is-in-progress) but if it's possible I'd rather not resort to start a third party program like insomnia every time I want to listen to music.

So are there a setting or a registry entry buried somewhere deep in windows that allows you to do this? Either for a group like "all audio" or for specific programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a batch file to launch spotify:

```
powercfg -change -standby-timeout-ac 0
start /wait "C:\Program Files\Spotify\spotify.exe"
powercfg -change -standby-timeout-ac 30
```

and launch it with [hstart](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/hstart.html) to hide the console window: `hstart /NOCONSOLE "launch spotify.bat"`

Comment: I would have preferred something more automatic for all things audio but this will work until Microsoft or the makers of Spotify comes up with something better. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

On win7 to permanently add "power saving exception" for specific application: start cmd and execute

> `powercfg -requestsoverride  process "[exe path]" DISPLAY SYSTEM`

For example:

> `powercfg -requestsoverride  process "C:\Program Files (x86)\DScaler\DScaler.exe" DISPLAY SYSTEM`

This seems to permanantly add "exception" - override to system

The exe path of Spotify is:

> "%AppData%\Spotify\Spotify.exe" 
>   or 
>   "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Spotify.exe"

Answer (score 0):

You can just go to the power options. Often done by right clicking the desktop and going to power management etc, if not open start and type in 'power' the correct result should show. 
Then just go to advanced and set 'sleep' to never. 
However this will also never put it to sleep ever, not just while using spotify.