# Windows 7 PC going to sleep while streaming video in web browser

Tags: windows-7, video, sleep, video-streaming

This odd behavior just started happening on my Windows 7-based HTPC in the last couple of weeks.  Whenever I'm watching video in my web browser (both Firefox and Chrome), the sleep setting of the PC kicks in and thus it goes to sleep.  It never used to do this, and when I look at the Power Settings, I have the following set:

Power Options -> Advanced Settings -> Multimedia settings -> When sharing media -> "Prevent idling to sleep"

as per other sites I've come across trying to solve the same problem.  However, this isn't helping matters.  Interestingly, when I'm watching a recorded television show via Windows Media Center, the PC stays awake the entire time.

Is there another setting somewhere that I need to ensure is set?  The only thing that changed between when this didn't happen and now is that I moved to a new home.  And I can't imagine how that would have somehow triggered this - I didn't change any settings on the PC before this started happening.

**Update/further notes:**

I did a test on my desktop PC with nothing else running other than my Firefox web browser, and it kept streaming a television show past my sleep timer without ever actually going to sleep, just as my HTPC used to until recently.  Also, and perhaps more telling, my HTPC never turns off the display before going to sleep, and that has a shorter time setting than the system sleep setting.  So, the PC is properly ignoring the display turn off setting when streaming web video, but not the sleep setting.  Very weird.

Comment: That setting has nothing to do with your problem. It's for when you're sharing media out to other devices.  Media player and other similar applications purposefully prevent Windows from sleeping while you're using them, whereas the browser won't do that. Check out the questions I'll mark as possible dupes for discussion and  solutions that could be applied.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to prevent the win7 sleep state while using spotify?](http://superuser.com/questions/108762/is-it-possible-to-prevent-the-win7-sleep-state-while-using-spotify), and [Prevent Windows 7 PC from sleeping while a download is in progress](http://superuser.com/questions/18285/prevent-windows-7-pc-from-sleeping-while-a-download-is-in-progress?rq=1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent display from turning off due to inactivity when watching full screen video (windows 7)](http://superuser.com/questions/99391/prevent-display-from-turning-off-due-to-inactivity-when-watching-full-screen-vid)

Comment: I appreciate these suggestions so far, though because I didn't need to use any of them before, I'm hoping for a solution that won't require me to use additional software/plugins or to set up a command-line workaround.

Comment: I'm hesitant to post this as an answer to my own question, since it's not really an ideal solution by any means.  However, I did eventually reinstall Windows 7 on my HTPC, and it made this behavior go away.