# How Can I keep my Computer from going to Sleep when certain programs are running but let it go to sleep when those program are not running ?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, power

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent Windows 7 PC from sleeping while a download is in progress](https://superuser.com/questions/18285/prevent-windows-7-pc-from-sleeping-while-a-download-is-in-progress)

"How Can I keep my Computer from going to Sleep when certain programs are running but let it go to sleep when those program are not running ?"

I got a program I've been using to trans-code a bunch of shows recorded in windows media center to a more compact format to save space. This process takes a long time to complete and often I return to the pc and it has went to "sleep" and stopped the programs progress.

I know I could go in and change my power settings to never sleep. while I'm doing this and change it back after. However, I would like to be able to have windows detect if this program is running and based on that decide rather to enter "sleep" mode.

Doing so would keep the computer awake even after the program finishes converting as it's still open but still it would be less hassle then having to change the power settings constantly, or just leaving the pc always "awake".

Comment: This question is very similar to http://superuser.com/q/18285/36459 Where a user wanted the pc to check for network activity or program being open before entering sleep mode, So you may find some information there to help in this case aswell. Especially incase this is closed as a duplicate. - Thanks