# stop computer from going to sleep when downloading

Tags: windows-7, download, sleep, standby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent Windows 7 PC from sleeping while a download is in progress](https://superuser.com/questions/18285/prevent-windows-7-pc-from-sleeping-while-a-download-is-in-progress)

I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate Edition and if I have a large download the computer goes to sleep (and the download is corrupted). How do I prevent it from going to sleep? What I don't get is why does it go to sleep - technically there still is hard disk activity.

Comment: Windows 7's presentation mode does the same. You can turn it on and off via the Mobility Center (Win+X).  I Cannot post this as an answer cause the question is protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going into your Control Panel>System & Security>Power options>Change when the computer sleeps and then change your settings so that it never goes to sleep.

I am not too much of an expert, but I think computers just go to sleep based on user input.

Comment: I did that but is there a better way? Now if I forget to turn off my computer (or the download completes) it's just sitting there.

Comment: @Celeritas What is the source of the download? Like a internet browser? Torrent site? etc.

Comment: Website but I'm using JDownloader.

Answer (score 1):

Either your downloader has to do it or you have to do it. JDownloader [doesn't do this yet](http://svn.jdownloader.org/issues/show/903) so you have to do it manually.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps to prevent automatic screen turnoff in windows 7.

1- Click  on the power icon in the system tray (beside clock) , and open up the More power options:

[image]

2- Under the “Additional plans” section, select High Performance, then “Change plan settings”:''

[image]

3- Change everything to “Never”.

[image]

4- Click on Save changes button.

Comment: The 'High Performance' plan also sets the minimum processor performance state to '100%' (among setting other non-power efficient settings), so it is not a good idea, IMO, to set it that way.