# Prevent Windows from shutting down if transfering file

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

Is there a way to prevent Windows from going to sleep mode if there are file transfers going on?

It is very annoying to have a massive GB file going over wireless only to close the lid for it to stop half way thru.

Comment: You can also make it so that when you close the lid on your laptop, it won't turn off the screen.  That may be an alternative solution.  HowTo: http://www.mydigitallife.info/disable-and-prevent-laptop-or-notebook-from-sleep-standby-or-hibernate-when-closing-the-lid/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent Windows 7 PC from sleeping while a download is in progress](http://superuser.com/questions/18285/prevent-windows-7-pc-from-sleeping-while-a-download-is-in-progress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Prevent Windows 7 PC from sleeping while a download is in progress](https://superuser.com/questions/18285/prevent-windows-7-pc-from-sleeping-while-a-download-is-in-progress)

This was answered somewhere else.  See if you can find the answer there.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I usually do is open `window media player`, play a song in repeat mode. It will keep windows always awake.